# pybind11: from c/c++ get number of arguments to python function

Tags: python, pybind11

In pybind11, I have a variable of type `pybind11::function`. Is there any way to determine how many arguments that function takes, in c++? I.e if it comes from `def f(a, b)`, the answer would be 2. I realize this might get crazy w/r *arks, kwargs, self, etc...

To be clear, this is inside of c++, so I'm looking for c++ code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here's how to do this in pybind11:

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <pybind11/embed.h>
pybind11::function callback_; // from somewhere!
pybind11::module inspect_module = pybind11::module::import("inspect");
pybind11::object result = inspect_module.attr("signature")(callback_).attr("parameters");
auto num_params = pybind11::len(result);
// num_params is an int
```

Answer (score 1):

**Here is how you can use [`inspect.signature()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.signature):**

```
from inspect import signature

import os # I only imported os to demonstrate with one of its functions

print(signature(os.remove)) # Print out the arguments for the remove fumction from the os module
```

Output:

```
(path, *, dir_fd=None)
```

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear: inside of c++, where I have a c++ variable of type pybind11::function.

Comment: hello @Colin. You can run the python code proposed by @Ann Zen directly from C++. See: https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/embedding.html#importing-modules. So it would be a matter of retrieving the `len` of `signature`